# How do you take input of a TextBox and return it in a TextBlock

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am new to MVVM and I am trying to type a string into a textbox and it return on a textblock on another page.

In my Views folder I have this code in xaml which is the textbox that I want to type into:

```
<TextBox x:Name="date" Text="{Binding Date}" Grid.Row="0" TextAlignment="Right" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="0 10 0 1" Padding="1" />
```

This is a different wpf page that has the textblock and I want what was typed in the textbox to appear here:

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="0" TextAlignment="Right" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="0 0 0 2" Padding="1" Text="{Binding Date}" />
```

In my Model folder I have the class Data Entry which looks like this:

```
public class DataEntry
    {
        public string Date { get; set; }


    }
```

In my ViewModels folder I have:

```
namespace FumeHood1._0._0.ViewModels
{
    public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public DataEntry DataEntry { get; set; }
        private string date;

        public string Date
        {
            get { return date; }
            set
            {
                date = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Date));
            }
        }




        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;




        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }


}
```

I have been looking everywhere and I cant find the right way to do it. If anyone could help it would be amazing. Just trying to make this MVVM pattern work and make more sense to me.

Comment: I think it should be `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Date));` instead of `OnPropertyChanged(Date);`.

Comment: @FrankM input parameter for `OnPropertyChanged` is string so nameof should not be the problem

Comment: @Bijan The parameter for `OnPropertyChanged` is supposed to be the name of the property that has changed, not its value. Therefore, it must be either `"Date"` or (preferrably) `nameof(Date)`. See [MSDN docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.propertychangedeventargs.propertyname(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

First, set the `DataContext` of your view.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window 
{
     public MainWindow() {
         InitializeComponent();
         DataContext = new MainViewModel();
     }
}
```

Or in xaml : (NOT both at the same time)

```
<Window>
    <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:MainViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
</Window>
```

And make sure the same instance of MainViewModel is used in both pages.

Second, carefully configure your bindings to act as intended:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Date, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWayToSource}"/>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Date}" />
```

Note that `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` makes sure that the view model property is updated while the user types. `Mode=OneWayToSource` only updates the view model property from the TextBox Text property, but not the other way round.

Comment: There's actually no reason to set Mode=OneWayToSource. If the view model property changes, don't you want to see that in the TextBox? And "make sure the same instance of MainViewModel is used in both pages" seems difficult when you create view model instances in XAML.